# tor for Android phone

Tags: configuration

Wondering the steps to take to make my note 8 totally anonymous so there's less chance of anything getting hacked after downloading tor system. Is it enough to just check all the boxes on apps under the orbit settings or do you need to take out all apps and restart them after downloading the network? Appreciate it if anyone knows for sure.

Comment: You will not be able to simply install an app or set of apps and make your phone totally anonymous or significantly more resistant to hacking.

Comment: don't use android (at least no stock android - or even worse with gapps) if you want to get really anonymous. **||** and anonymity has very little to nothing to do with hack-ability!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, open the orbot and just click **connect**.
And turn on the vpn, firstly because it hides your location from where you're using Tor. And secondly because guardian project wouldn't have included the vpn option in the orbot app if it was an anonymity compromising option.
Also,don't change any default settings in the orbot app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **basically** you can use an Orbot app and just connect. But digging deeper with TCPDump and WireShark tools it's going to be an AOSP with a custom build with custom `iptables` rules just right from the start - it's taking governance over the traffic a way more earlier than Orbot or *any* app. If you need a fully sealed isolation - use a separate hardware box like on Raspberry Pi or Asus TinkerBoard - there's no other way to make it safe and secure

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about the VPN tied to Orbot or Orfox. I will say this, from a security standpoint, it's always better running a VPN and TOR together as you may know. What's important here, is the privacy policy of the VPN service you use. Some will keep logs of traffic from your machine and if subpoenaed by the authorities subsequently have to turn them over. As an example if you were to purchase a subscription from a provider such as "Private Internet Access", you will clearly see that they keep no logs of any user activity. Meaning even if subpoenaed they won't be able to turn over any of your netflow because they don't record it.

You can get that particular service for $2.90 a month, or $40 for a year on multiple devices. I highly recommend it before connecting to the TOR network.

My apologies in advance for not being able to definitively answer your question. Also for any typos and my grammar. I'm still new to this, but happy to help if you have any further questions.

Kind Regards, 
Liquid

Comment: Wrong. It is not always better to run a VPN and Tor together. In most cases this is worse. The VPN providers policy doesn't matter, I've seen first hand the logs of VPN providers who claim they do not log. Beyond that, such logs are of little to no value over just logging the users connection to the VPN provider since a VPN provides little to no protection beyond what Tor is providing.

Comment: Could you please clarify how this makes things worse? Without a VPN your traffic runs unencrypted through the ISP. This gives the ISP the ability to see each address you are trying to reach in plain-text. However, with the VPN your traffic is encrypted at your device and passed through the ISP encrypted, to the VPN server, and from there you're considered "anonymous". Even though we both know you can never truly be anonymous. If you connect to TOR through a VPN your ISP can't see what information is going out OR coming in.

Comment: "Without a VPN your traffic runs unencrypted through the ISP. This gives the ISP the ability to see each address you are trying to reach in plain-text." <- Not if you're using Tor.

Comment: "VPN your traffic is encrypted at your device and passed through the ISP encrypted, to the VPN server, and from there you're considered "anonymous"." <- No, you are not, by any means, anonymous. The VPN is an ISP too.

Comment: "If you connect to TOR through a VPN your ISP can't see what information is going out OR coming in." <- this is also true if you just use Tor.

Comment: Using a VPN means you're connecting through a proxy, this is adding another "hop" to your connection. Adding more "hops" doesn't make your connection harder to deanonymize but it does add more places that your connection could be intercepted to be deanonymized. You are only *adding* risk to gain some very flimsy "cover".

Comment: Interesting, I see your point. However, (and this is an assumption) wouldn't a government who can trace layers of the onion back to its origin be impeded at the VPN server destination? As in the government would have to subpoena the VPN provider if it wanted to go that last step further to find your point of origin? If that were the case and this did happen (as it has before), the VPN would have to adhere to their privacy policy or risk being exposed as untruthful in practice and sued for violating the users agreement.

Comment: I will come back later to post sources. Also, I would like to point out that we agree about never truly being anonymous. If you'll notice, in the comment I posted yesterday, right after I said "you're considered anonymous" I wrote "Even though we both know you can never truly be anonymous".... I just wanted to clarify to you that we're on the same page in terms of that.

Comment: "wouldn't a government who can trace layers of the onion back to its origin be impeded at the VPN server destination" <- Not necessarily, there have been cases where while the VPN provider doesn't log, their upstream provider *did* log so the government just subpoenad them anyway. They also used times of VPN use against the PoodleCorp guys as evidence in the criminal complaint.

Comment: See my long-form writing of my thoughts on the subject [here](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/guide.md#vpns) and [here](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/misconception.md#vpns).